# API-Platform custom filtered collection as property

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I am using the api-platform (https://api-platform.com/) Framework for my website and I am trying to serialize a collection of an entity multiple times with different criteria. I have created the following example entities:

EntityWithFilteredCollection

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ApiResource(attributes={"normalization_context"={"groups"={"get"}}})
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class EntityWithFilteredCollection
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"get"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\FilteredCollectionRelatedEntity", mappedBy="relatedEntity")
     */
    private $relatedEntities;

    /**
     * @Groups({"get"})
     */
    private $filteredEntities;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->relatedEntities = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getRelatedEntities()
    {
        return $this->relatedEntities;
    }

    public function setRelatedEntities($relatedEntities)
    {
        $this->relatedEntities = $relatedEntities;
    }

    public function getFilteredEntities()
    {
        return $this->filteredEntities;
    }

    public function setFilteredEntities($filteredEntities)
    {
        $this->filteredEntities = $filteredEntities;
    }
}
```

FilteredCollectionRelatedEntity

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ApiResource(attributes={"normalization_context"={"groups"={"get"}}})
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class FilteredCollectionRelatedEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"get"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\RelatedEntity", inversedBy="relatedEntites")
     */
    protected $relatedEntity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"get"})
     */
    protected $value;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     * @Groups({"get"})
     */
    protected $condition;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getRelatedEntity()
    {
        return $this->relatedEntity;
    }

    public function setRelatedEntity($relatedEntity)
    {
        $this->relatedEntity = $relatedEntity;
    }

    public function getValue()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function setValue($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function getCondition()
    {
        return $this->condition;
    }

    public function setCondition($condition)
    {
        $this->condition = $condition;
    }
}
```

And an event subscriber for the Doctrine Post Load Event:

```
namespace AppBundle\EventSubscriber;


use AppBundle\Entity\EntityWithFilteredCollection;
use AppBundle\Entity\FilteredCollectionRelatedEntity;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;

class FilterCollectionSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    /** @var  RequestStack */
    private $requestStack;

    public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage, RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }


    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $event)
    {
        $entity = $event->getEntity();
        $method = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getMethod();


        if (!$entity instanceof EntityWithFilteredCollection || Request::METHOD_GET !== $method) {
            return;
        }

        $entity->setFilteredEntities($entity->getRelatedEntities()->filter(function (FilteredCollectionRelatedEntity $entity) {
            return $entity->getCondition();
        }));

    }

    /**
     * Returns an array of events this subscriber wants to listen to.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'postLoad'
        ];
    }
}
```

When I try to retrieve one EntityWithFilteredCollection which has some FilteredCollectionRelatedEntity entities which have the condition value set to true I get the following exception:

`No resource class found for object of type "AppBundle\Entity\FilteredCollectionRelatedEntity"`

Am I going the wrong path? Am I missing something?
When I don't try to serialize the filtered collection but the original one it works, but I get all entities.

Answer (score 1):

You should use custom API Platform's filters instead of a Doctrine listener: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters#creating-custom-filters

It will be easier to implement and faster to execute (the data will be filtered on the DBMS side instead of the PHP side).